# Run k3s in Rootless-mode

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, rootless

I'm trying to run k3s in rootless-mode. For now, i've done common steps from https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started and used unit-file from https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/blob/master/k3s-rootless.service

Systemd service k3s-rootless.service is active and run, but the pods are constantly in pending status.

I get these messages:

```
jun 21 20:43:58 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: E0621 20:43:58.647601      33 controller.go:116] loading OpenAPI spec for "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" failed with: failed to retrieve openAPI spec, http error: ResponseCode: 503, Body: service unavailable
jun 21 20:43:58 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: , Header: map[Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]]
jun 21 20:43:58 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: I0621 20:43:58.647876      33 controller.go:129] OpenAPI AggregationController: action for item v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io: Rate Limited Requeue.
jun 21 20:43:59 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:43:59Z" level=info msg="Waiting for control-plane node k3s-tspd.local startup: nodes \"k3s-tspd.local\" not found"
jun 21 20:44:00 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:44:00Z" level=info msg="Waiting for control-plane node k3s-tspd.local startup: nodes \"k3s-tspd.local\" not found"
jun 21 20:44:00 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:44:00Z" level=info msg="certificate CN=k3s-tspd.local signed by CN=k3s-server-ca@1655821591: notBefore=2022-06-21 14:26:31 +0000 UTC notAfter=2023-06-21 20:44:00 +0000 UTC"
jun 21 20:44:00 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:44:00Z" level=info msg="certificate CN=system:node:k3s-tspd.local,O=system:nodes signed by CN=k3s-client-ca@1655821591: notBefore=2022-06-21 14:26:31 +0000 UTC notAfter=2023-06-21 20:44:00 +0000 UTC"
jun 21 20:44:00 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:44:00Z" level=info msg="Waiting to retrieve agent configuration; server is not ready: \"fuse-overlayfs\" snapshotter cannot be enabled for \"/home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd\", try using \"native\": fuse-overlayfs not functional, make sure running with kernel >= 4.18: failed to mount fuse-overlayfs ({Type:fuse3.fuse-overlayfs Source:overlay Options:[lowerdir=/home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/lower2:/home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/lower1]}) on /home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/merged: mount helper [mount.fuse3 [overlay /home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/merged -o lowerdir=/home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/lower2:/home/scadauser/.rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/fuseoverlayfs-check751772682/lower1 -t fuse-overlayfs]] failed: \"\": exec: \"mount.fuse3\": executable file not found in $PATH"
jun 21 20:44:01 k3s-tspd.local k3s[1065]: time="2022-06-21T20:44:01Z" level=info msg="Waiting for control-plane node k3s-tspd.local startup: nodes \"k3s-tspd.local\" not found"


NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   helm-install-traefik-hn2nn                0/1     Pending   0          5h5m
kube-system   helm-install-traefik-crd-djr4j            0/1     Pending   0          5h5m
kube-system   local-path-provisioner-6c79684f77-w7fjb   0/1     Pending   0          5h5m
kube-system   metrics-server-7cd5fcb6b7-rlctn           0/1     Pending   0          5h5m
kube-system   coredns-d76bd69b-mjj4m                    0/1     Pending   0          15m
```

What should i do next?

Comment: Do you have more information? What is your system environment? Please provide `kubectl describe` output for your pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite obvious.
In unit file k3s-rootless.service I used the wrong snapshotter. For containerd in k3s rootless-mode it has to be '--snapshotter=fuse-overlayfs'.
fuse-overlayf also need to be installed before run k3s in rootless-mode.